# "New Year falls more often on Sundays than on Mondays"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, calendar-computations

This is a question from a hungarian math contest from the year 1948.

> It was Saturday on the 23rd October, 1948. Can one conclude that New Year falls more often on Sundays than on Mondays?

Well, I really have no idea how to start on this. It was on a contest and I am unsure what the contestants could use as aid, but I assume basically nothing. The question doesn´t say when there are leap years, altough the year 1948 WAS a leap year so contestants may be aware of the fact.

I have solution to the question in the book but I prefer to solve these problems on my own so I am preferably looking for some HINTS.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  this comes down to the exact [leap year rules](https://www.wwu.edu/skywise/leapyear.html)

Comment: Prove that the Gregorian calendar repeats every $400$ years.

Comment: Prove that 400 years reckoned using the Gregorian calendar is a whole number of weeks. (If it weren't, totals of e.g. the numbers of New Year's Days on the respective days of the week would even out over the course of 2800 years.)

Answer (score 1):

The number of years in a 400-year period that start on a given day of the week is seventy-one minus the number of leap years that start the day before (since each leap year causes a day of the week for January 1 to be skipped).

From 1601 to 2000, the leap years that started on Saturday were 1628, 1656, 1684, 1724, 1752, 1780, 1820, 1848, 1876, 1916, 1944, 1972, and 2000. (total=13)

Also, again from 1601 to 2000, the leap years that started on Sunday were 1612, 1640, 1668, 1696, 1708, 1736, 1764, 1792, 1804, 1832, 1860, 1888, 1928, 1956, and 1984. (total=15)

Hence, $71-13=58$ out of every 400 years start on Sunday, while $71-15=56$ out of every 400 years start on Monday. So, the quote in the title is indeed correct.